# What is the swimlane concept in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

What is the mearning/purpose of a swimlane in YouTrack (JetBrains)? Is it just a concept where you can group several normal tasks that in the end will make one big goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, that looks exactly what they are for.

http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/agile_project_management.html